# Send signals in iOS game

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

I'm developing a game and I'm wondering if it is possible to send signals.

In the first level the player needs 3 items to win

In the second level the player needs 5 items to win

Is it possible to throw a signal such as "ItemTaken" to a specific object which

1. knows the level
2. handles the signals
3. so it can compute whether the player has reached the next level or not

(I have simplified the thing but there are plenty of signals)

Comment: The term "signal" is used for a specific interaction between the OS and a process; it sounds like you're just talking about calling a method. Please be a _lot_ more specific -- a concrete pseudocode example would help a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as built-in API goes, you could look into `NSNotificationCenter`. The documentation is pretty straightforward: you can register to observe notifications, and post arbitrary notifications, which are identified by strings. So you could easily write something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyItemTakenNotification object:theTakenItem];
```

If you want something more sophisticated, you could take a look at [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). It's a framework for sending and responding to signals in a more sophisticated way. (I've never used it myself, however.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways.  One of the easiest is using `NSNotifications` and a singleton object.

Create singleton to listen for notifications and to handle them when they come in.  When the notification is received it will call the method that is the selector:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(processItem)
                                             name:@"kItemTaken"
                                           object:nil];
```

And have the app send notifications when events happen:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kItemTaken" object:nil];
```